# Find next number

Tags: mathematics, pattern

Find the next number from the following

```
19 => 730

28 => 520

37 => 370

45 => 189

63 => ?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number is

> 243

For the calculation rule

> consider the number on the left consisting of two digits $AB$. The number on the right is $(A \times A + B \times B - A \times B) \times (A + B)$

Comment: That expression is simpler to write as $A^3+B^3$.

Comment: Good catch, I should keep a paper at hand for these kind of riddles. :-)

Comment: @Moghwyn Reminds me about Counting the Legs and dividing by 4 Joke to determine the number of Cows in a farm.

Comment: @f'': Just for clarity -- the entire expression should be $(A^3 + B^3) \times (A + B)$?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain No. Check the math with both formulas.

Comment: @JoeM Thanks.  You're right, of course, it should just be $A^3 + B^3$.  I tried actually expanding out the equation in the answer, and ended up with $(A^3 + B^3) \times (A + B)$, but I must have made a mistake in my algebra somewhere.